# Proxy settings keeps resetting

Tags: network

I connect to the internet and randomly my proxy settings, 'web proxy' and 'secure web proxy' are checked which results in a very much slowed down connection. Each time it happens I go in and uncheck and 'apply' and after that it's good until next time I connect and it happens again. How can I stop this?

[image: proxy settings]

Comment: you are missing the entry in the Bypass proxy settings `*.local, 169.254/16"

Comment: These settings are most probably set by your DHCP server. You should fix this configuration on your DHCP server. The configuration you made is probably breaking your network architecture or security.

Comment: I have the same issue today with Monterrey (12.1) did you fix this issue?